# Where can one read about states?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

This term gets thrown around quite a lot on cogsci.SE. States (or maybe, to my understanding, states of mind, psychological states, or mental states) could be defined as schemas of a temporal nature (they last a certain period of time before the next one begins). Is there too little information in the question right now to get me any feedback? This is actually inspired by an answer from [another question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8601/how-other-than-pharmacotherapy-can-those-diagnosed-with-thought-disorders-be-t)

Comment: Are you after literature? A textbook? Or an explanation of "States of mind"?

Comment: I don't even know if there's a wiki article, so anything helps

Comment: Try "mental state" instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_state

Comment: If it 'gets thrown around quite a lot', possibly you could link to the question you do not fully understand to put this into context. Or, ask for clarification through a comment on the specific question? This question as it stands is very unclear what exactly you are looking for.